# String regex on sql

Tags: sql, regex, string

I have `"X1lNtWp4_e"` type of string on SQL code.

I wanna convert like `X1lNtWp4_e` without the `( " )`.

My DB Engine codes like MySQL I think.

I'm using http://chartio.com so i'm not sure which db engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chartio` is just a front end but assuming your DB is `MySQL` simply use:

Use the `TRIM` function with the `BOTH` argument:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM '"X1lNtWp4_e"')
FROM yourtable
```

Use the `REPLACE` function if the middle content contains `"` also and you want them removed:

```
SELECT REPLACE('"X1lNtWp4_e"', '"', '')
FROM yourtable
```